# How to find conditional expectation by evaluating a measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, conditional-expectation

I have the following exercise to do, and I am totally lost with it:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $X : \Omega → \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ a random variable with (cumulative) distribution function $F_X : \mathbb{R}_{\ge0} \to [0, 1]$. Further let $U_0 := X^{-1}
(\{0\})$ and
$U_n := X^{-1}
((n − 1, n])$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so that $\{U_{n}\}_{n\ge0}$ forms a partition of $\Omega$.
Construct the conditional expectation $E[X\mid\mathcal{H}]$ of $X$ with respect to the sub-$\sigma$-algebra
$\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{F}$ generated by $\{U_n\}$ by the following steps:

a) Evaluate the measure $Q(H) :=\int_{H}
X dP$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{H})$ for the sets $U_n \in \mathcal{H}$. Express
your result as an integral with respect to $F_X$.

b) For $n$ fixed, conclude that $E[X\mid\mathcal{H}]$ is constant on $U_n$. Determine $E[X\mid\mathcal{H}](\omega)$ for all
$\omega\in\Omega$.

---

The second part seems clear, but I am totally lost with the first part, I would totally appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_{U_n} X\, dP=\int_{(n-1,n]} x \, dF_X(x)$. [In general $\int \phi (X) \, dP=\int \phi(x)dF_X(x)$. Put $\phi (x)= xI_{(n-1,n]}$].   $E(X|\mathcal H)=\sum c_n I_{U_n}$ where $c_n$ is computed using the equation $\int_{U_n} X\, dP=c_nP(U_n)$. Hence $c_n=\frac {\int_{(n-1,n]} x \, dF_X(x)} {P(U_n)}$.